# use .find() with .attr()

Tags: jquery

I want to search the descendants of a JQuery search for `href`s.   I am thinking I should use the `.find()` method, but am having little success, as I'm not sure whether to pass the `.attr()` method as a parameter or as a subsequent method.

```
var trialMethod = function($this) {
  //Ive tried along the lines of this
  $this.find(.attr('href'));
  //and this
  $this.find().attr('href');
}
```

I am using a click handler (this one specifically attached to all the links, whether or not they were updated by JS/JQ), and trying to find the `href` of what is clicked.   Since I am trying to maximize the functionality of the site without JS, the links are static, then replaced via JS/JQ.   So when a link is clicked, it may be in a `<li>` or a `<span>` or whatever.   I am trying to keep convention to not declare the nth child element or the specific element, rather search since the DOM tree may change, hence looking for the `href` attribute, and I will check if a certain link is clicked.

1 - How do you find the `href`s of the child elements using the two methods `.find()` and `.attr()`?

2 - I have read the JQ API, but just want a bit of clarification; The `.find()` method ¿MUST? be passed a parameter?   if this is the case, then I now know not to waste time with attempts similar to my second attempt....

Comment: Please show your HTML, and explain what result you want to get?

Comment: are you trying to get the values of the attribute href or just want the elements that have the attribute href? i.e. "I want to get a list of links" or "I want the do something with the elements"

Comment: So this is a click handler? What's it attached to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all links with HREF attribute just use:

```
$(document).find('a[href]');
```

Same could be done for `rel` for example

```
$(document).find('a[rel]');
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean:

```
var allHrefs = $this.find("[href]").map(function() {
    return this.href;
}).get();
```

?